# Writing basic haskell function, taking Int x and doing function on [1..x]

Tags: list, function, haskell

I'm practicing some haskell, and having issues with something very basic in other languages.

I want my function to take an int and return a string

```
oddOnly :: Int -> String
```

and i want to print the output of that function

```
print (oddOnly 20)
```

I want this function to print all odd numbers from 1-20 for example

```
"1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19"
```

My function is only printing the final number obviously because i'm not iterating over a list of these numbers.  How do I do that?

```
oddOnly x
    | x < 0 = error "neg"
    | x == 0 = "0"
    | mod x 2 /= 0 = show x
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you make things too complicated here. You can use [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) here to filter a list, and use [**`odd :: Integral i => i`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:odd) as filter condition:

```
oddOnly :: Integral i => i -> [i]
oddOnly n = filter odd [1..n]
```

or as a string:

```
import Data.List(intercalate)

oddOnly :: (Show i, Integral i) => i -> String
oddOnly n = intercalate " " (map show (filter odd [1..n]))
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.List> putStrLn (oddOnly 15)
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15
```

> I'm not iterating over a list of these numbers. How do I do that?

Haskell's "workhorse" is recursion: you do not use `for` loops, etc. but you recurse on a list. You make recursive calls where you make a call with an different value, etc.

Comment: What if I want my type of function to be Int -> String

Comment: @Eddie: you intercalate :)

Comment: I thought there would be a way, at the beginning of the function to do something like let nums = [1..x] then somehow do recursion on it.  this language confuses me

Comment: @Eddie: we do recursion: the recursion is performed in the `filter`, `map` and `intercalate` function. But `let nums` is a bit strange, why not use `[1..x]` directly?

Comment: I'm using a very simplified example of a problem i have.  The idea is, I have the function with guards working for individual numbers, but I need to do this funciton to a list [1..x] where the input param is x

Comment: My real issue has nothing to do with odd or even, I'm just trying to grasp the idea of getting an input as an int, and doing some sort of iterative function on a list with that many numbers

Comment: @Eddie: well usually you try to define as much as possible in terms of `map`, `filter`, `foldr`, `zip`, etc. So `filter` can be used to filter your elements, `map` to convert items to something else, etc. You can use explicit recursion, but that is usually only a good idea if the above functions can not do that (conveniently).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198583/discussion-between-eddie-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: You *could* use `let`, but it's not necessary: `oddOnly n = let nums = [1..x] in intercalate " " (map show (filter odd nums))`.

Answer (score 4):

The most basic way to implement iteration in Haskell is by recursion.  There are fancier ways which Willem is trying to show you, but for some people (myself included) it's nice to see it done the basic way first.

A string of odd numbers, say `"1 3 5 7 ..."`, is an odd number `"1"` followed by a string of odd numbers `"3 5 7 ..."` (which is itself an odd number `"3"` followed by a string of odd numbers, etc.).  So if we already know how to make a string of odd numbers, we can put an odd number on the front of it to make a slightly longer string of odd numbers. This is the recursive structure of the problem.  Here's a try:

```
oddOnly :: Int -> String
oddOnly x
  | x < 0 = error "neg"
  | x == 0 = "0"
  | mod x 2 /= 0 = show x ++ " " ++ oddOnly (x + 2)
```

If we try this, we get something surprising:

```
ghci> oddOnly 1
"1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 ...
```

(your screen will fill up very fast with odd numbers)

We have constructed an infinitely long string of odd numbers (something Haskell happily lets us do :-).  We just need to terminate it -- that is, `oddOnly` now needs to *not* call itself if the argument is too big.

```
oddOnly :: Int -> String
oddOnly x
  | x < 0 = error "neg"
  | x == 0 = "0"
  | x >= 20 = ""
  | mod x 2 /= 0 = show x ++ " " ++ oddOnly (x + 2)
```

And we have what we are looking for.  Understand how that works?

See if you can modify this code to take the right endpoint as a parameter.  Maybe also take the step (here 2) as a parameter so you can get e.g. `"1 4 7 10"`.  Can you return a list instead and then write a separate function to turn them into a string `joinList :: [Int] -> String`  (this is good separation of concerns)?